# Celery: How to batch produce tasks?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a large loop to produce tasks:

```
for i in range(1000):
    receiver.apply_async(args=(i), kwargs={}, exchange=topic_exchange, routing_key=topic_key)
```

And I found there is a module `celery.contrib.batches` before celery 3.X or `celery_batches` after celery 4.X. But this module doesn't seem to support such params. So how can I do it?

I'm using celery 4.4.7 with rabbitmq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "batch" you mean a small subset (chunk) of the all tasks, then you could look into [Chunks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chunks). Instead of using chunks (they are after all made for different purpose), I suggest you use [Chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) if you care about results. If you do not, then just simply create a [Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups). Thousand tasks is nothing - we have had chords/groups made of tens of thousands of tasks and Celery copes with that load pretty well.

Comment: How about `kwargs`, `exchange` and `routing_key`? I guess I need to slice tasks by `routing_key` first, it is not so hard, but my kwargs are different for each task... or I must convert kwargs to args?

Comment: You can pass those to your signatures.

Comment: I tried `receiver.chunks(zip(range(1000)), 100)(kwargs={something}, exchange=topic_exchange, routing_key=topic_key)`, but kwargs still not work... So sorry I don't understand what 'pass those to your signatures' mean. Can you give me a simple example?